# How to get specific database error location in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In codeIgniter I see that if  query has error codeignter only show database error. but codeigniter doesn't say which file's line  error. here a example

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
      //some thing goes here
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\bata_shop\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Sometimes it difficult to find which query is  wrong. How do I get specific database error location in codeigniter?

Comment: It however tells you which queries went wrong, this can be leveraged. But to your point, codeigniter's limitation is there. Perhaps time to switch to more modern framework (if you are still early on in your development stage)?

Answer (score 3):

A dirty Solution for CI 2 and it helped me:-

Go and edit system\database\DB_driver.php and add the following code on line 321:-

```
echo "<pre>";
debug_print_backtrace();
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I knew this idea. but I'm little afraid for  use this. Because If It is suitable, why CI could not use directly?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due the database.php file not set correctly please check your database file  and all database related problem are in that file only

Comment: I am not understand your answer. If I was not set my database how was running correct query.

Comment: I was Trying to tell you that if there an database connection error they there is problem in that database.php file only this for the connection purpose